# error: cannot find symbol import after moving files using Explorer

Tags: java, netbeans, package, explorer

I'm having a very bizarre issue. I had a few files in one package

```
com.company.product.project.template
```

I decided that the files did not fit in that package and belonged in a different package. I moved those files to a new package.

```
com.company.product.platform
```

I did this using Windows explorer. I went into the moved java files and changed the package to the new location.

My IDE shows no errors but when i try to clean and build I get the error:

```
C:\Users\Mark\Documents\m\ide\My Project\My Module\src\com\company\product\project\template\PlatformVariantChangeWizardVisualPanel1.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
import com.company.product.platform.DeviceInfo;
  symbol:   class DeviceInfo
  location: package com.company.product.platform
```

My File PlatformVariantChangeWizardVisualPanel1.java has changed import

```
import com.company.product.platform.DeviceInfo;
```

and DeviceInfo.java package is changed to

```
package com.company.product.platform
```

I'm completely lost. I cannot seem to figure out how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try and refresh your IDE (assuming eclipse, I am sure IDEA has similar functionality)

Answer (score 0):

It's not an autoamted solution but it should get you out of the mess. The Java parser in NetBeans should already display an error icon beside the files and packages in the `Projects` window if some errors exists. Now follow those hints one by one, open the marked files and press `Ctrl+Shift+i` which will ideally fix anything unresolved automatically or at least show you a dialog to let you choose the correct imports for the unresolved symbols.

And for next time: in the `Project` window, right click on your package, select `Refactor|Rename...` or just `Ctrl+R`, change the name and click on `Refactor`. The same applies for classes.

Comment: No errors in netbeans. Only on clean and build. Sadly I don't have an elegant solution to move files (such as refactor) due to needing to use Surround as my version control. Pretty much I need to have surround move the files for me, then i pull from the repo.